# Correct enunciation of $ \, \sum \big( {Y_{i}}-{ \hat{Y}_{i}} \big)^2$

Tags: regression, notation

How can I enunciate this notation correctly, could you show me that, please?
$$ \sum \big( {Y_{i}}-{ \hat{Y}_{i}}  \big)^2 $$
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $\sum (Y_i-\hat{Y}_i)^2$? This expression is called [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares).

Comment: Yes, sir. In a formula, it is used very much. But, I just would like to learn its reading.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link by the way, I think I need to ask for a more specific help for this question. On the other hand, I have more idea now... :)

Comment: So, is there a typo in the original post or not, @KerimAtasoy? What you have written there is not the residual sum of squares and you never indicated whether Procrastinator had correctly spotted the error.

Comment: @Macro: No, sir, I have writen and sent it on a porpuse so that I could able to ask and learn about how to enunciate that notation correctly. I mean, I did not choose the exact formula to send, just a part of it.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're getting at. This is just the sum of the residuals of whatever fitted model this is. If it's an OLS model, this sum is 0 by definition. I'm not sure whether that helps...

Comment: Procrastinator and Macro, I think I see your point, but, in fact, I am not that good at Statistics for now, I have been studying Statistics because it is a part of my undergraduate programme. Thanks for the help... :)

Comment: @Macro His response "Yes, sir." indicates agreement that it should be a sum of squares instead of a sum and he is asking for enunciation rather than an abbreviation.  Well based on his response maybe not but that is how I interpreted it. The sum of deviations would not make sense as for least squares the sum of the residuals is always 0.

Comment: He could also be saying, "Yes, sir, I am sure it is not $\sum (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2$"....I'm pretty confused but the OP seems happy with the result so...I was really asking more so that I could edit the post accordingly but I'm still unsure about whether or not that should be done.

Comment: Yes, I got my answer for now... :) Thanks to all. And, please, do not argue so seriously for this question, somebody may be wrong, but, it is not a better solution to make that person uncomfortible or guilty for helping to an another person in need... :) THANKS. :)

Comment: Macro is correct that my use of the word sample mean would not be a proper description for Yˆi. But Yˆi is the regression estimate of the mean at the values of the predictors for Yi.

Comment: @KerimAtasoy, a big part of this site is to constructively criticize questions/answers when applicable, since we want others to be able to read the question/answer later and learn from it - this is why we've asked you for clarification and why I pointed out the standard use of notation to Michael. Michael and I have these kinds of back-and-forths on here a lot so I'm pretty sure I've not made him feel uncomfortable or guilty. Discussing (or what may seem like 'arguing seriously' about) statistics is something the regulars here enjoy, I hope :)

Comment: @KevinAtasoy I agree with Macro about constructive criticism.  We want to make sure that the answers are correct.  I have no problem with him correcting me about the use of the term sample mean and made corrections in my answer. I do find that occasionally but not at all in this case sarcastic remarks are made that really should not be said.  Macro is right that we have some very useful and pointed discussions about issues and technicalities.  It is all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is referred to as the sum of squared deviations from the means.  As Macro writes it can also be called the [residual sum of squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) when you view $\hat{Y}_i$ as model mean for the $i$'th observation and then $Y_i-\hat{Y}_i$ is the model residual for observation $i$.

Comment: Michael, $\hat{Y}_{i}$ doesn't usually refer to the sample mean - it's usually referring to the predicted value for observation $i$ from some fitted model.

Comment: Why are people downvoting my corrected answer?

Comment: I've upvoted it, Michael, but I think that it became clear after Jeromy gave his answer, that he had nailed what the OP was having trouble communicating - he wanted to know how to actually **say** the equation. In light of that, some people may be viewing your answer as somewhat off the mark, but I really don't know.

Answer (score 15):

It sounds like you are looking to learn how to pronounce the expression.
If you were going to speak fairly literally you could say

> The sum of WHY EYE minus WHY HAT EYE squared

or

> The sum of the quantity WHY EYE minus WHY HAT EYE, squared

However, when speaking to formulas it is common to get a little more abstract. And in such a formula $Y$ would typically refer to the variable being modelled and $\hat{Y}$ would refer to your prediction. Thus you could say things like:

> The sum of squared residuals

or

> the sum of squared differences between observed Y and predicted Y.

and presumably many other things.

I compiled a list of [mathematical pronunciation guides which you may find useful](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2009/05/pronunciation-guides-for-mathematical.html). In particular, you might want to have a look at [this one by H. VÄaliaho](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/engl.pdf).

Comment: +1! This interpretation makes the question so much clearer. This must be what was meant.